# Record from device speaker (not mic)

Tags: android

I am trying to record the device's speakers:

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);


    mediaRecorder.prepare(); 
    mediaRecorder.start();
```

this code records from the mic normally, but when i change the audio source to `DEFAULT` it breaks with exception.

I want a way to record from speakers with MediaRecorder or third party library.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Recording from a device's speaker makes no sense technically as the electronics circuitry is not designed so hence you must probably mean something else, right?

Comment: i am trying to record what the device playing, ie music track from music player

Comment: If you're playing a media file that already exists on the device what you probably want is (audio) transcoding. There are apps for that. And in the case you want to add sound to a recorded video, you can also merge the sound file with the recorded video.

Comment: did you find any solution? @Nasha Some phones doesn't support call recording so if we record speaker output + mic input separately and merge them later will give us call recording feature.

Comment: @AhmadNawaz I used to initial source to get the data directly. I was streaming data so I captured the data directly.